# Why can a Boost.Bind function be called with extra parameters?

Tags: c++, boost, functional-programming, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void foo(std::string const& dummy)
{
    std::cout << "Yo: " << dummy << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int* test;
    std::string bar("platypus");
    (boost::bind(&foo, bar))(test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test);
}
```

When run, it prints out, "Yo: platypus." It appears to completely ignore extra parameters. I'd expect to get a compile error. I accidentally introduced a bug into my code this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this is allowed, but I do know it is expected behavior. From [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions):

> bind can handle functions with more
>   than two arguments, and its argument
>   substitution mechanism is more
>   general:
>
> ```
> bind(f, _2, _1)(x, y);                 // f(y, x)
> bind(g, _1, 9, _1)(x);                 // g(x, 9, x)
> bind(g, _3, _3, _3)(x, y, z);          // g(z, z, z)
> bind(g, _1, _1, _1)(x, y, z);          // g(x, x, x)
> ```
>
> Note that, in the last example, the
>   function object produced by bind(g,
>   _1, _1, _1) does not contain references to any arguments beyond the
>   first, but it can still be used with
>   more than one argument. *Any extra
>   arguments are silently ignored* (emphasis mine), just
>   like the first and the second argument
>   are ignored in the third example.

Comment: I'd still love to know the reasoning for why to allow this behavior if anyone finds out :)

Comment: @Joseph: Likely just too complex to explicitly disallow it.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's creating the bound function as a variadic function, like `printf`.

Comment: Nope. The argument count has a fixed, [implementation-defined limit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html#NumberOfArguments). The current limit is nine.